# Referring to a CSS file in a HTML Email

Tags: html, css, spring, email, thymeleaf

I have a project on Thymeleaf + Spring MVC, and trying to use Thymeleaf to send HTML emails.

I was under the impression that only thing that I had to do was to create a template file, and pass the parameters like I've been doing for the regular pages. It looks like I was wrong. When I do that, it doesn't apply the CSS. (As a matter of fact it doesn't even refer to the CSS file.) I don't know whether Google is the one removing the CSS file or something all the mail clients do.

It looks like Google also encode the class and IDs of the HTML elements, so is my only option using inline CSS or is there a way to reference a CSS file in an HTML email?

```
<img src="some_url" class="CToWUd">
```

Above is what the img tag looks like on Gmail. It should look like this though:

```
<img src="some_url" class="topImage" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, linking to external stylesheets in HTML email is very poorly supported.

Also, Gmail actually strips `style` tags from both the `head` and the `body`, so you really need to push all of your styles inline before you send, to make sure that Gmail doesn't remove them.

Campaign Monitor has a great [CSS Support Guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) which outlines what you can and can't use across all email clients.

Comment: Like you said, I had to push all the styles inline for it to work. Thanks for the CSS Support Guide, it really helped me choose what to use.

Comment: I wanted to use Material UI CSS in my email templates, but it probably contained a lot of CSS that is not supported by Gmail.
I deleted unnecessary and unsupported attributes/selectors from the CSS file, substituted it into the template programmatically, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

It's common for the `head` tag to be removed from e-mails automatically, Gmail definitely does this.

Try referencing the stylesheet in the `body` instead.

Failing that, you could put the CSS in a `style` tag in the body:

```
<html>

<body>

<style>
    p {
        // style here
    }
</style>

// Rest of HTML here

</body>

</html>
```